# How do I scrape dynamic URL of a page?

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, selenium

I am trying to do some website testing through selenium and python. I did fill the page http://www.flightcentre.co.nz/ and submitted the form. But now the search result is taking me to a new page with URL - https://secure.flightcentre.co.nz/eyWD/results . How does my web driver now will handle this? I am doing this for the first time. Could any one help me by providing an example or point me to a right tutorial of this sort.

Thanks.

Comment: 1.You will have to show us what you have tried . 2. You can do this my shifting the focus of your tab to new window just google it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok since I tried to answer your other question I'll give it a go on this one although you are not exactly explaining what you want.

One thing to remember is Selenium is running your browser and not a traditional web scraper.  Which means if the url changes it's not a big deal, the only time you have to change how you approach scraping in selenium is when you get a popup.

One thing you can do from your other code is when looking for a flight do a

```
driver.implicitly_wait(40)//40 is the amount of seconds
```

this will wait for at least 40 seconds before crashing, and then start whenever the page finishes loading, or whatever you want to do next is active in the dom.

Now if you are trying to scrape all of the flight data that comes up, that'll be fairly tricky.  You could do a for loop and grab every element on a page and write it to a csv file.

```
class_for_departure_flight = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="iata"]')
for flights in class_for_departure_flight:
            try:
                with open('my_flights.csv', 'a', newline='') as flights_book:
                csv_writer = csv.writer(flights_book, delimiter = ',')
                csv_writer.writerow(flights.text)
            except:
                print("Missed a flight")
```

Things to take notice in this second part is I am using the CSV library in Python to write rows of data.  A note you can append a bunch of data together and write it as one row like:

```
data = (flights, dates, times)
csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

and it will right all of those different things on the same row in a spreadsheet.

The other two big things that are easily missed are:

```
class_for_departure_flight = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="iata"]')
```

that is driver.find_**elements**_by_xpath, you'll notice elements is plural, which means it is looking for multiple objects with the same class_name and it will store them in an array so you can iterate over them in a for loop.

The next part is csv_writer.writerow(**flights.text**) when you iterate over your flights, you need to grab the text to do that  you do flights.text.  If you were to do this with just a search function you could do something like this as well.

```
class_for_departure_flight = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="iata"]').text
```

hopefully this helps!

Comment: That makes lot of sense. I didn't know that the URL change is not going to affect it. That clarifies my whole doubt. Rest is bonus for me.. Thanks a lot. And in the previous question, alex's iterated solution solved the issue. :)

Comment: That's great!  Goodluck with this project it's definitely not an easy thing to scrape a travel agency website for stuff.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good place to start: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html

Here are some things about Selenium I've learned the hard way:

1) When the DOM refreshes, you lose your references to page objects (i.e. return from something like element = driver.find_element_by_id("passwd-id"), element is now stale)

2) Test shallow; each test case should do only one assert/validation of page state, maybe two. This enables you to take screen shots when there's a failure and save you from dealing with "is it a failure in the test, or the app?"

3) It's a big race condition between any JavaScript on the page, and Selenium. Use Explicit Waits to block Selenium while the JavaScript works to refresh the DOM.

To be clear, this is my experience with using Selenium; thus not universal to everyone's experience.

Good luck! Hope this is helpful.